# API gives 200 Success but object does not change Python

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm calling this api to cancel an order in my app. After I call the api, I get a success message, but, nothing changes. Here is the code I'm using:

API

```
@csrf_exempt
def customer_reset_order(request):
    customer = get_user(request)
    if not customer:
        return JsonResponse({'invalid token'})

        order = Order.objects.filter(
            id=request.POST["order_id"],
            status=Order.READY
        )
        order.status = Order.CANCELED

        order.save()

    return JsonResponse({"status": "reset"})
```

Why can I call the api but, see no change?

Comment: "_I'm calling this api to cancel an order in my app_" -  which api, which app?

Comment: It seems that you are editing your order into `if not customer` statement.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an indentation issue. You are editing the order into `if not customer` statement.

Just indent correctly ;)

```
@csrf_exempt
def customer_reset_order(request):
    customer = get_user(request)
    if not customer:
        return JsonResponse({'invalid token'})

    # .get() to retrieve 1 result. .filter() returns a Queryset
    order = Order.objects.get(
        id=request.POST["order_id"],
        status=Order.READY
    )
    order.status = Order.CANCELED

    order.save()

    return JsonResponse({"status": "reset"})
```

Comment: I'm getting the query error: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save' after formatting

Comment: Ok, that is because you are "filtering" when retrieving the order. `.filter()` retrieves a queryset. You can use `.get()` instead, if you are sure that only 1 result will be retrieved. I will edit the answer as well.

Comment: You can also leave `.filter()` and access the first element using `[0]`. But using `.get()` is a better solution IMO.

Comment: I am not the who upvoted it. I have the same error after indenting and removing the .filter for .get.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it worked. Could you print `order` and `order.status`, please? Is `order` a Queryset or `Order` instance?